# Xcode: Select object which is beyond storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I'm finalising my app. I use storyboard for this app, and I have a slide out UIView that is under the screen. I designed the slider in the storyboard, and when it was complete, I moved it right under the screen, where it should be at the launch of app. Now, I'm trying to change something about it in the storyboard, but I can't select it because I can't reach it with the mouse, since its beyond the storyboard. Is there any way to get it back, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .xib file, look in the lower-left corner.  You should see a button that looks like this:

[image: button]

Click on it, and you will see all of your user interface objects.  Click on an object to select it.